# Can a positive definite matrix have an eigenvalue equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a square symmetric matrix. I want to check if it is positive definite. I understand that according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations) if all the eigenvalues are positive, the matrix is positive definite.  I don't know if this means $\lambda$>0 or if it means $\lambda \geq$0. Because I have $\lambda$=0.

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_%28number%29#Mathematics) zero isn't positive or negative. I am just a little confused on this topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A *Positive Definite* has full rank: all its eigenvalues are strictly positive.

A square symmetric matrix with non-negative eigenvalues (*i.e.*, eigenvalues that are positive or zero) is called *Positive Semi-Definite* (PSD).

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful!

Answer (score 6):

A positive definite symmetric matrix has *strictly* positive eigenvalues. If $0$ were an eigenvalue, the matrix would be singular since its kernel would be non-zero, which contradicts positive definiteness.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful!